# multiple WebGLRenderer s for a WebGLRenderTarget

Tags: three.js

Using three.js, WebGLRenderer and WebGLRenderTarget.

I'm trying to:

```
1 - render scene A to renderTargetA with renderer A
2 - use renderTargetA.texture on a Mesh added to scene B
3 - render scene B to canvas with renderer B
```

If I use the same renderer for everything, it works.
But if I act like explained it won't ( It looks like WebGLRenderTarget.texture.image is undefined )

Do you know what's happening (I suppose it's normal for how THREE.js implements render targets) and if there it is a workaround?

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ac30kohj/4/
(switch between lines 66 / 67)

Thanks a lot

Comment: This scenario is not supported since the actual `WebGLTexture` object is cached in an internal `properties` object of the renderer. You have to use the same instance of `WebGLRenderer`. What is your use case for using two different renderers?

Comment: thanks for the clarification @Mugen87.
Well, I'm building a multi-scene narrative experience; every scene has its own rendering settings (autoclear, pixel ratio, etc) and a WebGLRenderTarget.
Given the situation I'll do something like:
1- scene[ x {0 to n} ].render():
   - animate
   - set main renderer parameters
   - render scene[0] to its WebGLRenderTarget

2- use scene[x].renderTarget.texture in the custom material plane in the main scene for postprocessing / transitions